# how to use one of the attribute value to get another attribute value in the same table in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After the user has made an appointment, the attribute(user id, date, time) is stored in the appointment table with the therapist push id as the parent node(to facilitate the retrieval of certain doctor's appointment).

Now, in the user interface, I need to get all the attribute by using the user id. Does anyone know how to do it?

Here is my database structure

[image: database struc]

Here is my own code

```
a=new ArrayList<AppointmentObject>();

databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //to get current log in user id
        String userid1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.child("appointment").getChildren()) {

            //if the userid stored is same as user id, it will be added to arraylist
            if(dataSnapshot1.getValue(AppointmentObject.class).getUserid().equals(userid1)){
                AppointmentObject thera= dataSnapshot1.getValue(AppointmentObject.class);
                a.add(thera);
            }
        }

        adapter=new MyRecyclerviewPAppointment(MainActivityPAppointment.this, a);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

However, it appears this error

[image: error]

Comment: For future, please include all textual content as text (no screenshots) as that makes them searchable en reusable. For the database JSON, you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

Your NullPointerException comes from this line

```java
if(dataSnapshot1.getValue(AppointmentObject.class).getUserid().equals(userid1)) {}
```

One of these fields is null `dataSnapshot1, dataSnapshot1.getValue(), dataSnapshot1.getValue().getUserid()`

To ensure your code will compile **reverse** order of comparison:

```java
if(userid1.equals(dataSnapshot1.getValue(AppointmentObject.class).getUserid())) {}
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it